# useEffect to get firebase data not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Ok so i use the useEffect to get firebase firestore data. This is my hook code:

```
 const [campaign, setCampaigns] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    var docRef = db.collection("campaigns").doc(slug);

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
          console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
              setCampaigns(doc.data()) 
      } else {
          // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
          console.log("No such document!");
      }
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
  },[]);

 console.log(campaign[0].startDate.seconds) // gives the error stated below
 console.log(campaign.images[0].url)// gives the error stated below
```

The response is:
[image]

I can get access to all the top level properties such as body, campaignPolicy etc. but if I do

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined

If I do campaign.startDate.seconds i get same error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined

Full minimal code:

```
const ReviewComponent = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = useState([])
  const [currentCampaign, setCurrentCampaign] = useState([])

//First useEffect hook
  const tempDoc = []
      useEffect(() => {
        var docRef = db.collection("campaigns");
        docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            tempDoc.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
              // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
              setCampaigns(tempDoc)
          });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
      },[]);


//Second use effect hook
      useEffect(() => {
        const docRef = db.collection("campaigns").doc(slug);
    
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                setCurrentCampaign(doc.data()) 
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    },[]);


  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  if(currentCampaign[0]) { // Or if(campaign[0])

    console.log(currentCampaign)
  }

  return(
    <Typography>
    {currentCampaign.reviews[0].text}
   </Typography>
)
```

Comment: You are trying to access an array like an object. Try campaign[0].startDate.seconds instead.

Comment: None of the code you shared seems to be accessing `seconds`, so it seems unlikely the error is coming from this code. Please make sure your question contains the [minimal, complete/standalone code with which any of us can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am just doing console.log(campaign[0].startDate.seconds) right under the useEffect hook

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access your data before they are retrieved. Here is what happens:

// First render

1. You set your state as an empty array
2. You declare an effect with a callback that will be called **after** the first render
3. You try to access a value that is indeed undefined (your array is empty at this point) and your app crash

// Second render

Your code crash at the first render but if it didn't:

1. Your state now contains your data
2. Your effect will not be called as you have an empty dependency array
3. You can use your data

To make your code work, and you should do it every time you load data asynchronously, is to check that your data are loaded.

```
const [campaign, setCampaigns] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = db.collection("campaigns").doc(slug);

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            setCampaigns(doc.data()) 
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
  });
},[]);

if(campaign.length > 0) { // Or if(campaign[0])
  console.log(campaign[0].startDate.seconds)
  console.log(campaign[0].images[0].url)
}
```

Comment: It still throws the same error even when I want to use the data within the return statement. Only things such as campaign[0].id or campaign[0].couponPrice (which are all the top level properties) work. Anything that is nested such as campaign[0].images[0].url throws same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: Can you create a minimum code base that throws the error?

Comment: Ok, I add it to my main post

Comment: You seem to mix types for the current campain, at one point its an array, then an object. Check the type you need and stick with it. And I don't see any check for undefined values in your render.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of campaign is empty array and it is set after few time from firebase store.
So you should check campaign state what is empty or has value.

```
if (campaign.length == 0)
    console.log(campaign[0].startDate.seconds);
```

Comment: I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDate' of undefined. So it is saying campaign is undefined, but if I do console.log(campaign) it displays the entire object as shown in the picture provided in my original post